# Undefined name 'text'

Tags: flutter, dart, text

Is there a way to write text? Because the name "text" is not recognized

```dart
onTap: () {
            setState(
              () {
                text = 'Locations Tapped!';
              },
            );
          }
```

```dart
onTap: () {
            setState(
              () {
                text = 'Locations Tapped!';
              },
            );
          }
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve], it's rather unclear why you expect the name "text" to be recognized as something. Did you define it?

Comment: The problem is that I'm a very novice at Flutter, so I don't even know how to make MWE, I just try to get something here

Comment: If you don't know how you do something, reading a book or tutorial is a good first step. Guessing is not, it just wastes everybody's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define `String text;` and then assign value to it.
or you can use `print('your text')` to write on console

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write in console or terminal use `print('Location Tapped!');`

or `log('Location tapped!");`

it works similar to `print()` in `python` and other language.

And if you want to save the value create a variable and than save it like

```
String text;
text='location tapped!!';
```